# Start making IOS app from Android app

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I've been working hard to finish making my Android app, and now it's time to make an IOS version too.

I've noticed that Mac computer is needed to start with IOS apps, so I came into few questions since I don't have any Mac device in my home:

1) What is the most affordable developement enviroment for IOS developement?

2) Is there any tool or guide for Android --> IOS?

3) What is  Xamarin? Does it allow to build apps for android & IOS together? and how effective it will be since I already made my Android app via Android Studio?

Looking for answers, 
Thanks in advance.

I did not find answer to this questions in the web. what I found is 5 years old aged irrelevant answers.

Comment: Did you try to search for the information on the web before asking the question?

Comment: Yes. I did not find answer to this questions in the web. what I found is 5 years old and irrelevant.

Comment: 1) most affordable is prob using OSX in a virtual machine
2) not really, best you will get is a guide, never heard of one though
3) Xamarin lets you make your app cross platform, but you will probably have to start over and make it in xamarin, at least app should be consistent for both platforms

Comment: 1. OSX in virtual machine is not working anymore as I read. 3. Making the app for IOS now is start over anyway....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

congratulations for your new app.

1) You can have a look for OS X servers http://www.macincloud.com but in the long term I think it would be time and money saving to just buy a second hand Mac computer or a Mac Mini for 500 dollars or so.

2) They use different syntax and different APIs, so you won't be able to reuse most of your knowledge, I'd recommend you to have a look to the iTunes University Stanford videos.

3) Xamarin is a mobile cross platform framework, the main advantage is that your code is converted into native one, so the final touch uses real native components. In that case you have to use C# for the development and, of course, redo the whole project.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! I'll buy some second hand mac computer. About Xamarin, I know that IOS developement is C#, so I need to redo my whole project anyway. My question is if to use the Xamarin or the XCODE?

Comment: You are a bit confused, Xcode is an Apple product and you can use Swift or Objective-C for development.

Xamarin is something completely unrelated to Apple and you need to use C# for development, the advantage is that you can (in theory) do the project once in C# and deploy to at least 3 platforms: iOS, Android and Windows Phone. There are some drawbacks obviously.